# Spring Boot JASYPT Failure Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password'

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

We currently have JASYPT running in boot 2.2.4, jasypt 3.0.2 with not issues. Only exception is the jasypt passphrase is obtained from a DB from a postProcessEnvironment event.

The new Spring Boot 2.3.2, Jaspt 3.0.2 throws the following on startup.

```
13:27:42.380 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatStarter onStartup - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to java.lang.String
13:27:42.471 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter report -
```

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.ver>0.8.2</jacoco-maven-plugin.ver>
        <jasypt.spring.boot.starter.ver>3.0.3</jasypt.spring.boot.starter.ver>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JASYPT Encryption -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${jasypt.spring.boot.starter.ver}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
.....
```

```
jasypt:
  encryptor:
    password: fubar
    #iv-generator-classname: org.jasypt.RandomIvGenerator
    #iv-generator-classname: org.jasypt.NoIvGenerator
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://myDb;databaseName=BAR;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
    username: Bullwincle
    password: ENC(dX8PMJjtC04JBzjSMllTop6s2/seBDHo)
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 60000
      maximum-pool-size: 5
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    show-sql: false
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class MyApplication {
```

I do not have a custom Encryptor bean

Application starts with non-encrypted password.

TRIED:

iv-generator-classname: org.jasypt.NoIvGenerator

iv-generator-classname: org.jasypt.RandomIvGenerator

If I down grade  JASYPT to 2.1.2 the application starts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to their [release notes](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot#update-11242019-version-300-release-includes) default encryption algorithm has been changed in 3.0.0 so what they suggest is to set these:

```
jasypt:
  encryptor:
    algorithm: PBEWithMD5AndDES
    iv-generator-classname: org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is irrelavant of version, if your `jasypt.encryptor.password` is not the password that you used to encrypt your passwords, then it would fail also because it cant decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

You must control default value for your version. Here's [a link](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot#update-11242019-version-300-release-includes)
For example for my problem:
I changed jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname=org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
to
jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname=org.jasypt.iv.RandomIvGenerator